# Different Cron Expression for day and night

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

Is there a way to create a cron expression to run for every half an hour during the day and every 4 hours during the night?

I am using this cron expression inside a cloud scheduler that runs the GCP cloud function.

Comment: From the cron tag: Questions about configuring cron for systems or administration are OFF TOPIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
0,30 7-23,0-6/4 * * *
```

So this runs on every `0`th and `30`th minute of the hour from `7` til `23` and then every `4`th hour from `0` to `6`.

You can also [have crontab.guru explain it](https://crontab.guru/#0,30_7-23,0-6/4_*_*_*) to you.